# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm using the following code, trying to send the JSON line to the client, for testing purposes:

```
String json = "{'nombre':'Donell', 'dni':'351351P'}";
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(json);
            out.print(jsonObj);
```

I'm using the library json-simple, but this isn't working. When I access to "/Prueba", which is my test servlet, I receive a package with 200 code type "json", but without data:

[image]

What's wrong here? Thank you!

edit: When trying to just write the json, I see it, but with an error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have the json string in variable `json` simply print this string to the response:

```
response.getWriter().print(json);
```

Also the json string should use double quotes

```
"{\"nombre\":\"Donell\", \"dni\":\"351351P\"}"
```

(When you parsed the old invalid string, you got a `null` JSONObject and therefore you saw a `null` in the response, when printing the object).

Comment: That's right, now the json string is visible. I'm getting a strange error tho, check my edit

Comment: @Zerok that is because you use single quotes in the JSON string, you need double quotes (see my answer).